# How do I get more info from Gmail's virus warning?

Tags: gmail

A customer reported that he's getting a Gmail virus warning while trying to e-mail around one of our applications.  We believe it to be a false positive (as we've had a false positive with another scanner's heuristic engine because our application includes an installer).

I'd like to confirm that it's really not a virus of course (and other virus scanners don't find anything at the moment), but unfortunately Gmail just reports a less than helpful page and strips the attachment.  Is there any way to get more information out of Gmail as to what exactly it thinks it found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve more information from Gmail's virus warning. One usual workaround is to compress the application into some format that is not analyzed by Gmail antivirus, such as 7z.